# Не работает второй POST-запрос после вызова первого POST-запроса

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Не срабатывает второй POST-запрос после вызова первого POST-запроса.

При нажатии на кнопку поиска формируется ответ, вот скрипт на кнопку:

```
$(function() {

$("#searchfellow").click(function() {

        var fellowTypeId    = $("#fellowTypeId").val();
        var typeId          = $("#typeId").val();
        var age             = $("#age").val();
        var fellowAgeStart  = $("#fellowAgeStart").val();
        var fellowAgeEnd    = $("#fellowAgeEnd").val();
        var countryId       = $("#countryId").val();
        var days            = $("#days").val();
        var cityId          = $("#cityId").val();
        var fellowMonthId   = $("#fellowMonthId").val();

        var data = 'fellowTypeId='+fellowTypeId+'&typeId='+typeId+'&age='+age+'&fellowAgeStart='+fellowAgeStart+'&fellowAgeEnd='+fellowAgeEnd+'&countryId='+countryId+'&days='+days+'&cityId='+cityId+'&fellowMonthId='+fellowMonthId;

        if(fellowTypeId) {
        var Label_xhr;
            // делаем ajax запрос
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax-search-fellows.php",
                data: data,
                // выполнится  до AJAX запроса
                beforeSend: function(html) {
              $("#search-query").html('');
                    $("#progress-search-fellows").show();
               },
               // выполнится после AJAX запроса
               success: function(html){ 
                  if (Label_xhr) Label_xhr.abort();
                Label_xhr=setTimeout(function() {
              $("#progress-search-fellows").hide();
                    $("#search-query").show();
              jQuery.scrollTo('#search-query',300);
                    $("#search-query").html(html);
            },1000);
              }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Далее, в подгруженных данных есть ссылка "Показать телефон". При нажатии на ссылку "Показать" выполняется второй запрос и отображается телефон:

```
// Показать номер телефона

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.getPhone').click(function(){

      var _this = $(this).parent().parent();
      var pid = _this.find('.pid').val();
        var data    = 'pid='+pid;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax-get-phone.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function(html) {
                _this.find('.getPhone').html('Загрузка...');
            },
            success: function(html){
            setTimeout(function() {
                _this.find('.getPhone').hide();
                _this.find(".divPhone").html(html);},250);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Проблема в том, что второй скрипт (номер телефона) не срабатывает, направляет на главную сайта. Без выполнения первого запроса, второй работает отлично.

Comment: `.getPhone` добавляется наверное из AJAX ? 

попробуйте 

    $(document).on('click','.getPhone',function(){

вместо 

    $('.getPhone').click(function(){

Comment: var data = $('#searchfellow').parents('form').serialize();
Это заменит весь код выше ajax-запроса.

Comment: Спасибо. Только хотела спросить :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите после

```
$('.getPhone').click(function(){
```

строку

```
console.log('Щелчок на .getPhone'); // После нажатия проверьте консоль браузера
```

или

```
alert('Щелчок на .getPhone'); // После нажатия должно появиться диалоговое окно
```

Если сообщения не появляются, значит скорее всего вам необходимо делегировать событие click на элементе $('.getPhone')

Сделать это можно с помощью метода [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on1) например так:

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", ".getPhone", function() {
  alert('Щелчок на .getPhone');
});
```

В вашем случае достаточно заменить

```
$('.getPhone').click(function(){
```

на

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", ".getPhone", function() {
```

Comment: Лисёнок, работает!

Comment: Еще вопрос. Может быть в таком случае правильно было бы всегда писать $( "div" ).on( "click", ".getPhone", function() {  вместо $('.getPhone').click(function(){ , а это значит, что и $("#searchfellow").click(function() { следовало бы заменить на $( "div" ).on( "click", "#searchfellow", function() {, или пусть остается как было?

Comment: Для $("#searchfellow") у вас уже установлены обработчики событий, поэтому думаю не имеет смысла. Лучше обратите внимание на комментарий Lucky выше.

Comment: да, я уже исправила.